# php include in WAMP working selectively

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

Here is an approximation of my folder/file structure in the www folder of WAMP on my machine...

```
- entities
  - file00.php
  - file01.php
  - file03.php
- factories
  - file00.php
  - file01.php
  - file03.php
- shared
  - views
    - file00.php
    - file01.php
    - file03.php
    - subfolder
      - file00.php
      - file01.php
      - file03.php
  - etc.
- toolkit
  - file00.php
index.php
other.php
```

When using `<?php include('shared/views/[any file.php]') ?>` by either `index.php` or `other.php` there's no problem reading or working with the file. However, using `<?php include('factories/[any file].php') ?>` or `<?php include('tookit/file00.php') ?>` in those files yields a "failed to open stream: No such file or directory" from WAMP listing a path using which I can easily open the file with Windows Explorer.

The same issue occurs if I try to use `include '../factories/[any file].php';` in the `toolkit/file00.php` while the factories folder using `include '../entities/[any file].php';` has no problem working with those scripts at all. My paths are correct, I'm using an IDE that validates those file paths, I can navigate to the files by the path that WAMP says doesn't host them. Why is this selective inclusion happening? Any advice would be very appreciated.

**NOTE:** Just in case this was a TFS/Source Safe type of issue, I checked the properties of the files and folders. All of them are Read-Only in the root folder, and yet some work and some don't.

Comment: What happens when you try to access the file directly from the URL (even if the file isn't meant to be accessed there)?  Do you get a 404 Error, or a 401 Error?  Have you made sure you don't have any invisible .htaccess files, or checked your set-up of the htconfig.conf file?

Comment: There are no errors when I just try to navigate to it in the address bar. There are no invisible `.htaccess` files and my `htconfig` file has not been modified from the default yet.

Comment: Are you running anything else that may conflict with your WAMP server?  I know Skype is one of them (you must start your WAMP server before running Skype).  Also, what happens if you open the permissions wide (chmod 777, recursively).  Just to temporarily test...

Comment: Unless there's some sort of secret, WAMP-interfering software running in the background, no, nothing is conflicting with WAMP. Opening the file permissions does nothing. I've already tried this.

Comment: Just guessing now, but have you tried changing using the "current directory" indicator, `./`?  So `include('factories/[any file].php') ?>` becomes `include('./factories/[any file].php') ?>`

Comment: Just tried it. Bubcus.